# 'end' expected near '<eof>' for map import for lua file

Tags: lua, love2d

```
Error

Syntax error: main.lua:8: 'end' expected (to close 'function' at line 5) near '<eof>'
Traceback
[love "callbacks.lua"]:228: in function 'handler'
[C]: at 0x010558a810
[C]: in function 'require'
[C]: in function 'xpcall'
[C]: in function 'xpcall'
```

I am getting the above error when I am trying to import a game map for my love2D game.
My code is below:

```
function love.load()
    sti = require'lib/sti'
    gameMap = sti('Maps/test_map.lua')
end

function love.draw()
    gameMap:draw()
end
```

sti is a library which I am using to get the map into love. I learnt this from a youtube  tutorial.

Comment: There's no syntax error in that code.

Comment: Do you have any idea what could be causing the error?

Comment: It may be caused by forgetting an `end` on some function or other block of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try looking at the function `gameMap:draw`, you might have forgotten an `end` on it